# Django query complex query in one to one field model

Tags: django

I have two models of Student and Parent

Student models.py:

```py
class StudentInfo(models.Model):
    admissionNumber = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True,default=0)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    fullName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True)
    classSection = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Parent models.py

```py
class ParentInfo(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(StudentInfo,primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fatherName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    motherName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I have a form to search students through their fatherName.

So, what I want is to filter those students whose father's name contains 'some name'.

I tried this but it resultes in query set of ParentInfo:

```py
   parentInfo = ParentInfo.objects.all()
   studentsInfo = parentInfo.filter(parent__fName = fName).select_related('student')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should filter the opposite way, like:

```
StudentInfo.objects.filter(parentinfo__fatherName='name of father')
```

You here thus obtain a `QuerySet` of `StudentInfo`s which contains zero, one, or more `StudentInfo`s where there is a *related* `ParentInfo` object where the `fatherName` field is, in this case *`'Name of father'`*.

> **Note**: It might be better to implement a `ForeignKey` in the opposite order, such that multiple students can refer to the *same* `ParentInfo` object. Right now, a `ParentInfo` object can refer to exactly *one* `StudentInfo`. If there are students with the same parents (so siblings), then you introduce data duplication in the database.

Comment: Hi, Willem this query results in error as Cannot resolve keyword 'parentinfo' into field

Comment: @YashBoura: did you set a `related_name` in your `ForeignKey`?

Comment: oops sorry yeah I did and putting that in query I got the result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
# You can use contains attribute on the field of model and your query can be like this

student = models.ParentInfo.objects.values('student__firstName', 'student__lastName').filter(fatherName__contains='your value')


print(student[0]['student__firstName'])

print(student[0]['student__lastName'])
```

Comment: Thanks got my answer but this method is an option too!